# class files not created under maven target directory in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have created a simple maven project to create shaded jar. I built it using mvn clean compile .It creates jar file but after extracting it i don't see .class files corresponding to my project java source files. I see clearly below message when i build but don't see any .class files under target dir.

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ PersonalizationFeeder ---

[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!

[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!

[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to Documents/PersonalizationFeeder/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

What is the problem here?  My pom.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>data-analytics</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.wooplr</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>PersonalizationFeeder</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <userlib.dir>Documents/userlibs</userlib.dir>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wooplr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${userlib.dir}/jedis-2.7.3.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>

                            <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <!--<artifact>*:*</artifact>-->
                            <excludes>
                                <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: What do you have in `Documents/PersonalizationFeeder/target/classes`? What you expect is not clear and what has IntelliJ to do in this?

Comment: Why have you explicitly set the location of your java source files (`<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>`). That should not be necessary. How does the jar look by the way if you remove the `maven-shade-plugin`.

Comment: @RC : Documents/PersonalizationFeeder/target/classes directory is empty.Ideally it should create .class files of my source files right? What I expect is, my shaded jar (once it gets created)  should contain the .class files of my source files. But I don't see them.Am I doing any wrong thing here?

Comment: @uniknow, I tried without explicitly setting the sourceDirectory as well, but it didn't create .class files of my source files. With or without maven-shade-plugin, .class files are not included in created jar.

Comment: Can you use a different tool to double-check .class files are not there? Such as windows explorer or command line? It's possible that they are created, but filtered out from view.

Comment: The log you posted states that 10 files are compiled and class files created in `Documents/PersonalizationFeeder/target/classes`. Can you check with your explorer (assuming you are using windows) whether the classes exist in there.

Comment: I use Mac and checked with explorer and command line but not found any .class files. As an attempt, I copied my source files into another very similar maven project that is creating .class files properly and built it with mvn clean compile). Then I found .class files got created but after I extract in the final shaded jar(using jar -xf abc.jar) I don't find any .class files.

Comment: Problem solved...!!
In one of the dependency jars, there is licenced jar and because of which it couldn't build properly. To solve the problem,I had to extract that particular dependency jar and remove *.RSA,*.DSA and *.SF files from META-INF/ dir and then make it jar using jar -cf command and then use this new jar as dependency. It worked fine for me.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...!! In one of the dependency jars, there is licenced jar and because of which it couldn't build properly. To solve the problem,I had to extract that particular dependency jar and remove .RSA,.DSA and *.SF files from META-INF/ dir and then make it jar using jar -cf command and then use this new jar as dependency. It worked fine for me. Thanks all.